# In GVim, preven ALE from changing syntax color, but still underlines errors

Tags: syntax-highlighting, plugin-ale

I am using gVim and Asynchronous Lint Engine (ALE) for linting Python scripts. I was capable to fully customize my own Python syntax highlighting, with one exception.

I can't find a way to prevent ALE from changing the color of the character where the linted error was detected **and** at the same keeping the blue/red underlines that indicate errors (notice the letter 'd' changes color):

[image: s]

If I do `let g:ale_set_highlights = 0`, ALE does not change the characters' colors, but then I also loose the blue/red underlining that you in the image above.

How could I solve that?

Comment: Can you try different colorschemes? I suspect it might be an issue there

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I tried two and the issue persists. In any case, even if it has to do with colorschemes, I would like to learn how to alter those properly in order to avoid the problem